# Numerics & List Manipulation:ListCorrelate: yield $\{-f1 + f2, \dots, -f2 + f4, \dots\}$ from $\{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5\}$

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value, correlation

The command

```
 ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}]
```

yields

> {-f1 + f2, -f2 + f3, -f3 + f4, -f4 + f5}

is there any simple way to get

> {-f1 + f2, -f1 + f3, -f2 + f4, -f3 + f5, -f4 + f5}

using ListCorrelate or similar command? I need it to approximate derivative in numerical integration. Also interested in itself as list-manipulating technique.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find a pattern in the desired output that you describe. Would you please add some detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListCorrelate[{-1, 0, 1}, {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, {2, 2}, "Fixed"]
```

> {-f1 + f2, -f1 + f3, -f2 + f4, -f3 + f5, -f4 + f5}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad) to extend your list, and use the kernel `{-1, 0, 1}`:

```
list = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

ListCorrelate[{-1, 0, 1}, ArrayPad[list, 1, "Fixed"]]
```

> {-f1 + f2, -f1 + f3, -f2 + f4, -f3 + f5, -f4 + f5}

Comment: What is the functionality of {2, 2}, "Fixed"] ?

Comment: Also: which is the right way of citing Mathematica output in a question?